# Align DialogBar in Frame and set its width

Tags: layout, mfc

I'm working on an MFC project which was transferred to me.
It's basic layout (main frame derived from `CFrameWnd`) is shown in this sketch:
[image: MainFrame layout]

The `CommandBar` and the `ControlBar`, both derived from `CDialogBar`, were created using `WS_CHILD | CBRS_ALIGN_RIGHT` as style.
This is fine for the alignment. But I would like to **define the widths** of these two elements and cannot find a way to set it.

When I tried to `EnableDocking` for the dialog bars, I couldn't manage to resolve the assertions. Also I'm not sure if this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding [CalcDynamicLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/3y36zdka.aspx) and returning the calculated size is what I was looking for.

Example:

```
CSize CommandBar::CalcDynamicLayout(int nLength, DWORD dwMode)
{
    CSize size;
    CRect parentRect;
    if (GetParent())
        GetParent()->GetClientRect(&parentRect);
    size.cy = parentRect.Height();
    size.cx = (int)(abs(parentRect.Width() - parentRect.Height() + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMENUSIZE)) * 0.5);
    return size;
}
```